# Using DateTimeConstants(JodaTime) value to store dayOfTheWeek in database?

Tags: java, database, jodatime

I need to store a dayOfTheWeek in a column of my database. Im using HSQLDB. Also, Im already using JodaTime for other types, like Timestamp.
Im thinking about encapsulate the int or string values into a class, so JodaTIme has already int values for the Constants, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc...

Is this a good or bad idea? Like if somewhat JodaTime decides to change the values for the days
Or should I store something different? Like creating my own enum...

Comment: well the big question if how you want your queries to be after the database mapping? I think there exists some 'native' support for Joda for certain application servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int values for day-of-week are defined by ISO-8601 and won't be changing. As such, they are safe to store in a database. If you want to go further, you could create an enum/class to wrap the value, but I don't think that is really adding value with Joda-Time (JSR-310/ThreeTen has a DayOfWeek enum).